# Is 閣閣 a real word?

Tags: words, dictionary

As the title says, is [閣閣](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%96%A3%E9%96%A3) a real word? I've searched through weblio古語辞典 and [BCCWJ](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/string_search?commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&string_search%5Bgenres%5D=PN_core%2CPN%2CPM_core%2CPM%2CPB_core%2CPB%2CLB_core%2CLB%2COW%2COB%2COC_core%2COC%2COY_core%2COY%2COL%2COM%2COP%2COT%2COV&string_search%5Bwords%5D=%E9%96%A3%E9%96%A3&string_search%5Byears%5D=1971%2C1972%2C1973%2C1974%2C1975%2C1976%2C1977%2C1978%2C1979%2C1980%2C1981%2C1982%2C1983%2C1984%2C1985%2C1986%2C1987%2C1988%2C1989%2C1990%2C1991%2C1992%2C1993%2C1994%2C1995%2C1996%2C1997%2C1998%2C1999%2C2000%2C2001%2C2002%2C2003%2C2004%2C2005%2C2006%2C2007%2C2008&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and I've gotten no results that are not 内閣閣僚. Out of pure curiosity, I just want to find a real example of this word being used (or just word testimony that a native speaker has heard or used it). Then again, maybe it's just another fob in jisho.org's source dictionary.

Comment: Since it is listed as obscure, archaic, literary, the first thing that came to my mind would be searching through haiku, tanka, etc., I also noticed that there was a Chinese reading of 'ge', which may or may not be coincidental to the ge, ge, ge and gero, gero image of frogs cries.

Comment: The annotation ('to' particle etc)  suggests it may be confusion with [赫赫](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B5%AB%E8%B5%AB).

Comment: A bit curious about the entry on this Japanese Dictionary: https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E5%AD%A6%E7%A0%94%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E5%A4%A7%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/content/68012_1340

Comment: @AndrewT. Interesting! The entry says that the word was used in a book called 自然と人生 which was published in 1900. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditto @[naruto's](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/5010/) findings.

> Is this a real word?

Yes.

In Chinese, apparently.

The top hits at [https://www.google.com/search?q="閣閣"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E9%96%A3%E9%96%A3%22) are all for Chinese sites discussing the word, implying that this isn't terribly well known in that language community either.

Note also the simplified Chinese script version:

## 阁阁

> Then again, maybe it's just another fob in jisho.org's source dictionary.

Sure looks like a goof.  While this does apparently appear in texts that are nominally Japanese, as naruto notes, these are all in Chinese contexts -- texts deliberately evincing a Classical Chinese mood.  As such, in linguistic terms, this could be viewed more as [code switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching), where writers / readers / speakers of Language A who are also knowledgeable about Language B deliberately mix in some words from Language B.

From what I'm seeing, I would classify this as Classical Chinese, not Japanese, and not in use in modern Chinese either.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard or seen it. This seems to be more of an (old?) Chinese onomatopoeia ({{zh-cn:阁阁}}). Most Japanese articles that contain this word (e.g., [this](http://www7b.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Erakusyotei/kansi-27.html) and [this](http://www.randdmanagement.com/c_chi/ch_244.htm)) seem to be related to old Chinese literature. I checked 青空文庫全文検索 (which contains older materials than BCCWJ) and found no relevant results.